# Animation at the same time as the mouse path - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, drag-and-drop, draggable

I would like to know if you can or cannot (and if you can, how) to make an animation that moves forward and backward as the mouse moves. If the mouse clicks on the object that activates the animation and the mouse moves to the left, the animation advances, and if the mouse moves to the right, the animation moves backwards. Thank you very much in advance.
This is the code in c#

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        Point coor;
        Point coorMouse;
        Point newCoorMouse;
        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();

        private void path1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            coor.X = e.GetPosition(path1).X;
            coorMouse.X = e.GetPosition(this).X;
        }

        public int Posicion() 
        {
            if (coorMouse.X - newCoorMouse.X > 0)
            {
                int posicion = Convert.ToInt32(coorMouse.X - newCoorMouse.X);
                return posicion;
            }
            else
            {
                int posicion = -(Convert.ToInt32(coorMouse.X - newCoorMouse.X));
                return posicion;
            }
        }

        private void path1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            sb = FindResource("BienvenidoAnima") as Storyboard;
            newCoorMouse.X = e.GetPosition(this).X;

            if (Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                if ((Mouse.GetPosition(this).X - coor.X) < coorMouse.X)
                {

                    sb.Begin(this, true);
                    sb.Seek(this, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, Posicion()), TimeSeekOrigin.BeginTime);

                }

                if ((Mouse.GetPosition(this).X - coor.X) > coorMouse.X)
                {
                    sb.AutoReverse = true;

                    sb.Seek(this, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0 ,0 , Posicion()), TimeSeekOrigin.BeginTime);
                }
            }
            if (Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Released)
            {
                
                sb.AutoReverse = false;
            }

        }
```

The code of xaml

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="BienvenidoAnima">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="0"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock1">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.9" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}"/>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock1">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}"/>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="path">
                <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="-0.018"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="path">
                <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="-403.175"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)" Storyboard.TargetName="path1">
                <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="0"/>
                <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="0,0,800,0"/>
            </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>




    <Grid OpacityMask="#FF131313">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Background="#FF131313" BorderBrush="#FF131313" Foreground="White" FontSize="60" Content="Mama" Template="{DynamicResource BotonBoton1}"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Background="#FF131313" BorderBrush="#FF131313" Foreground="White" FontSize="60" Style="{DynamicResource BotonBoton2}" Content="Papa" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="0" Background="#FF131313" BorderBrush="#FF131313" Foreground="White" FontSize="60" Style="{DynamicResource BotonBoton3}" Content="Hermano" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Button Background="#FF131313" BorderBrush="#FF131313" Foreground="White" FontSize="60" Style="{DynamicResource BotonBoton4}" Content="Abuela" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
        <Grid x:Name="Bienvenido" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2">

            <Path x:Name="path" Data="M0,450 L0,0 800,0 800,450" Fill="#FF131313"  Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Path.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Path.RenderTransform>
            </Path>
            <Path x:Name="path1" Data="M800,450 L800,0 C750,200 750,250 800,450" Fill="Black"  Margin="732,0,0,0" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                  MouseDown="path1_MouseDown"
                  MouseMove="path1_MouseMove">
                <Path.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Path.RenderTransform>
            </Path>

            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Text="Bienvenido" Foreground="White" Margin="10,10,384.54,298.523" FontSize="80"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" Text="Desliza hacia la IZQUIERDA" Foreground="White" Margin="483.746,357.619,60,27.094" FontSize="20"/>

        </Grid>

    </Grid>
```

Comment: There are multiple questions here. Do you know how to get the mouse's position? Do you know how raise an event when the mouse moves? Do you know how to do animations? Do you know how to modify animations?

Comment: Oh, I know how to get the mouse position, I know how to generate an event when the mouse moves, I do animations, I don't know what exactly you mean by modifying animations.

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried so far?

Comment: Do you need animations at all, or just an element that follows the mouse simply be setting its position on each mouse move event?

Comment: Yes, i need animations.